# Heroku Discord Bot "No web processes running"

Tags: java, heroku, discord, bots

So I've written a lot of code (Java) for a Discord bot, and when I run it in Eclipse it works as intended and the bot will respond when I send messages in Discord. I used Maven and the JDA Builder to make the bot.

However, when I push it to Heroku to host it, it will build successfully, but then I get this message:

```
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"
```

My Procfile is

```
Writer: java Bot.java
```

What should I do to fix it? I am very new to coding and I couldn't find answers to help me online.

Answer (score 0):

The Procfile is incorrect, it should be `worker` instead of `writer`, for example

```
worker: java -jar app.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I changed my Procfile to `worker: java Bot.java`, but I still get the same error message. Any other suggestions? If not I'll figure something out. Thank you

Comment: The error is when you try to open the app (accessing the homepage), if you need to server HTTP requests you need to use `web` instead of `worker`. However Discord bots are normally workers as they don't need to receive HTTP requests

Comment: Oh my gosh, I'm so dumb, that makes so much sense lol... one more question if you don't mind: so my Procfile is `worker: java TMCBot/TMCBot/Bot.java`, (I copied the exact path to the main class from its Github page) and when the dyno turns on the logs say `Starting process with command 'java TMCBot/TMCBot/Bot.java'`, and then it crashes and says `Error: could not find or load main class TMCBot.TMCBot.Bot.java`. Is there a problem with the way I tried to get the main class in the Procfile? Thank you for all of your responses.

Comment: It should be `java com.foo.app.App` where com.foo.app is the package and App is the Java .class

Comment: So now I have my Bot.java in a package called "TMCBot". My Procfile is exactly `worker: java TMCBot.Bot.java`. I've also tried `worker: java TMCBot.Bot.class`. I trial and error tweaked syntax for a while now, i think I'm just dumb lol

Comment: Without .java at the end: `worker: java TMCBot.Bot`, post the new error logs if it still doesnt work

Comment: I still get `Error: Could not find or load main class TMCBot.Bot`.